# Can we do a CU patching on Trial version of SP2010 or 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching, trial-version

We are planning to test SharePoint CU patching activity on one of our test server where trial version of SP2010/2013 is installed.

Can we do a CU patching on Trial version of SP2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 1):

As a short answer **Yes**, you can.

The Cumulative update doesn't care about it was a `trail` or `licensed`.It cares about the SharePoint Edition:

- Foundation.
- Standard.
- Enterprise.

So before installing a new CU. you should be aware of

- What's your current SharePoint Edition?
- What's the latest Cumulative update that already installed?
- What are the current issues that will be solved after applying the CU? So I can decide Which Cumulative update should I install?
- What's the prerequisite of the Cumulative update that you indent to install?

For more details check [Find the latest Cumulative Update / Farm Patch Level that has been installed in a SharePoint Farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-the-latest-cu-farm-patch-level-that-already-installed-in-your-sharepoint-farm/)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your trial period not expired, **Yes** you can apply patch on that farm. There is no such restriction for the trail version.

Patches only check the Install version of the SharePoint ( Foundation or Server) and don't care about the License type ( Trial or Standard or Enterprise).